# How to pass credit card detail directly at payment in Paypal Android SDK?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, credit-card, paypal

I have successfully  completed payment process with PayPal Android SDK.  now, I have credit card detail and want to pass it at payment time. I've already tried many examples and methods. none of its seems work. Any help would be appreciated.